# how to fix button size equal width depends on text what is the class for these

Tags: button

I[I in image button are not in fixed width it's changes depends on size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQzV3.png) am trying to fix button size for equal width depends on text but it's not taking what is the class for that.

Comment: Which environment are you working in? Web, Android, iOS? Also, please add a bit more description about the code you tried, and outcome you expected.

Comment: Please format properly first..Add some snippet what you have tried yet and where exactly you get the problem and which languages do u used for that

Comment: I am using in web.....